# How to find IP of load balancer for a domain?

Tags: networking

In a firewall do I have to write the IP addresses I need access to. Many sites have a load balancer in front, so I would like to find the IP for it.

If I use `google.com` as an example

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:     172.24.1.131
Address:    172.24.1.131#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.207.206
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400f:80b::200e
```

## Question

Is `216.58.207.206` the IP of the `google.com` load balancer or it just the IP of one of the hosts behind the load balancer?

If it is host a work host, how do I find the IP of the load balancer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific point of time when you made the DNS query, yes, `216.58.207.206` is the IP address where your broser will connect when you go to `google.com`. It doesn't matter if it is a load balancer or real web server, it is still the address you need to allow.

However, in general, allowing only specific IP addresses doesn't work with the general internet.

- Web sites often use CDN servers for static assets. The IP addresses for CDN servers will change over time
- Web sites use multiple discrete servers for serving web page resources. For example, connecting to `cnn.com` makes web server fetch resources from 30+ domains.
- Some sites are deployed in environments where their IP address changes on every deployment

In order to make a working allow list in the firewall, you would need to write software that constantly monitors all the resources needed by allowed web sites. The software then would add update the IP addresses in firewall configuration.

In practice, allowing modern web sites by IP addresses is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Small websites use a single server or several ones with a load balancer in front of them, but big ones (like Google or Microsoft or Facebook) will use a mix of several techniques to increase availability and to serve your request from the nearest geographical location.

What this means in practice is, when you query DNS for *those* sites, you can get all kind of different IP addresses to connect to.

You need a firewall which can filter based on the requested URL and implement policies such as "allow access to `google.com`"; if you are limited to filtering on IP addresses, you simply can't keep up with modern big web sites/services.